# How to use timeit to compare dict lookup and set lookup

Tags: python, timeit

I really don't understand this

```
import timeit
d = {'a':0,
     'b':0,
     'c':0}
s = {'a','b','c'}

t = timeit.Timer('a' in (d))
t.timeit()
```

is dict key lookup as fast as set membership lookup?

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. `'a' in (d)` just evaluates to `True`, so this is passing `True` to `timeit.Timer`.

Comment: [As expected, if you try to run this, Python just yells at you about the nonsense parameter to `timeit.Timer`.](http://ideone.com/HHW0w4)

Comment: well I tried putting 'if' and 'print' in there but that didn't work

Comment: try `timeit.timeit(stmt="'a' in d",setup="d = {'a':0, 'b':0,  'c':0}; s = set(d)")` and switch d for s. There's a slight difference, yes.

Comment: what is your question exactly BTW? you can't use `timeit` ? or you want to know which is faster? set or dict lookup?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well ultimately I was trying to answer the question which is faster with membership lookups, sets or dicts or if the difference is negligible with 20,000 members

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm guessing they both use hashing and so have very similar lookup times, but thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a flexible protocol: create a big dictionary with 20000 members using (fixed) random values (there may be less than 20000 values if some values are repeated), create a set from the keys, and test `in` for both.

```
import timeit

for i in ['the_dict','the_set']:
    print("{} {}".format(i,timeit.timeit(stmt="'a' in "+i,setup="import random; random.seed(0); the_dict = {random.randint(0,100000000):0 for _ in range(20000)}; the_set = set(the_dict)")))
```

I wouldn't jump to conclusions though: for 2 different runs:

```
>>> 
the_dict 0.04250915015789406
the_set 0.03894365848696617
>>> 
*** Console de processus distant Réinitialisée *** 
>>> 
the_dict 0.03786818274290301
the_set 0.04610909810692078
>>>
```

The difference of time at this point is probably very low-level (cache hit/miss), and not related to python. Both use hashing. If there dict were faster than the sets by design, no-one would use sets...